# How make the bot say a different response when the result of the dice is 20 and 1?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots, discord.js

Example:

Result is 1 = He respond: The result is 1, luckier next time!

Result is 20 = He respond: The result is 20, congratulations!

The code the code for now is:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    var response = [Math.floor(Math.random() * ((20 - 1) + 1) + 1)];

   message.channel.send("The result is " + response + "!").then().catch(console.error);  

   if (response === 20) {
   message.channel.send("The result is " + response + ", congratulations!").then().catch(console.error);
   }
   if (response === 1) {
   message.channel.send("The result is " + response + ", luckier next time!").then().catch(console.error);
}
}
```

I tried, but he just answered "("The result is " + response + "!")"...

Comment: @Levi_OP As the answer already states.

Comment: your always get `The result is " + response + "!` because it's not in a condition. if all that's changing is the string you only need one instance of `message.channel.send`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As previously mentioned, you were not correctly assigning the random value. You can also create an object of responses, removing the need for several if statements.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((20 - 1) + 1) + 1);
    
    let response = {
       1:  ", luckier next time!",
       2:  ...
       .
       .
       .
       19: ...
       20: ", congratulations!"
    }

    message.channel.send("The result is " + result + response[result]).then().catch(console.error);  

   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears you've set your var `response` to an array, but you're strict testing it against an integer using `===`.

Try removing the square brackets around your statement:

```
var response = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((20 - 1) + 1) + 1);
```